# Lightning Component not visible on Community for given profile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder, user-profile

I have a community built using Napili template. there is one particular Lightning Component which is visible to a user from one profile but not for another profile. Here are some things we already checked-

1. Both the profiles are seeing the same page variation.
2. I am not getting any Exception/ Error Message in Debug. (the controller for the community is not even called in the debug)
3. I am not getting any error in the Console Debug (Inspect Element in Browser)
4. I am not seeing the page getting marked Hidden with CSS- it's not in the Page Source code.

Any idea how to debug this? Any help will be appreciated.

thanks.